# Error con urllib.request: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>

Tags: python

[Python 3.7.3] Estoy escribiendo un script para descargar vídeos de YouTube usando el módulo `pytube`. Al ejecutar las operaciones desde el shell de Python en la consola, funciona sin problemas. Sin embargo, al realizarlo desde el script, salta el siguiente error.

```
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\Python\ordenar.py", line 7, in <module>
    YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WTu2xaXgnQ').streams.first().download()
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.prefetch_init()
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 96, in prefetch_init
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 160, in prefetch
    self.watch_html = request.get(url=self.watch_url)
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 21, in get
    response = urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 548, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Anmova\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1387, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Lo mismo ocurre al ejecutar

```
urllib.request.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115803/urllib-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-unknown-url-type-https')
```

[En esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115803/urllib-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-unknown-url-type-https) se topan con el mismo error y lo arreglan, pero no consigo aplicar la solución.

Comment: Sólo se me ocurren tres respuestas: 1) Tu instalación de python está rota. 2) La cadena "https" al inicio de la URL no es lo que parece (contiene algún carácter invisible o no-ascii). 3) Mejor usas [`youtube-dl`](https://youtube-dl.org/)